# WordPress permalinks and .htaccess file issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm using the WordPress .htaccess file as follows

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This is not working for my permalink /%postname%

What might be the problem?

Comment: Maybe you have WP inside a subdir?

Comment: if WP is inside a subdir change RewriteBase to /subdir/

Comment: my WP is in root directory

Comment: Are you sure that you set "use permalinks" in blog's settings??

Comment: Well, where can i find this setting??

Comment: Check my answer, have all you need to use permalinks in WP

Comment: @NomikOS Place the link to your answer, not to your profile.

Comment: @felipe you wrong mate. profile you say is the comment's signature. My answer is in [this same page](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14059024/333061) thanks anyway. 8)

Comment: The .htaccess WP rule set does not have anything to do with the problem. Is not there where WP manages rewrites (Check /wp-includes/rewrite.php) Maybe you need to start WP again and go to the permalinks settings page to refresh and update them. You don't mention the WP version, by the way.

Comment: @NomikOS My mistake. But you got it, the link to the answer was missing. That's what I meant.

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA I'll start doing what you suggest, Is the best, Thanks!

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA my wordpress version in 3.5 thanx for the suggestion but nothing works.
What should i do with rewrite.php file??

Comment: Nothing, I was just pointing out where the rewrite is done. You have a leading slash in `/%postname%`. Remove it and try. ¿Are you sure the mod_rewrite module is enabled? If it is, try disabling all plugins. I don't think the problem is related to rewrites or rules in the htaccess file.

Comment: Unless the `RewriteBase /` is wrong. It must map to the folder where WP is installed. If it is not in the root but in a subdirectory i.e. `mydomain.com/wp/` the base must be: `RewriteBase /wp` and `RewriteRule . wp/index.php [L]` must have the correct path, as shown.

Comment: Missed the leading slash in my previous comment, it should be: `RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]`

Answer (score 2):

1.- Be sure that your set permalinks in `Permalink Settings` http:// your_domain/wp-admin/options-permalink.php

[image]

2.- If you are using WP inside a subdir you must modify htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /subdir/
```

**UPDATE**:

3.- enable rewrite module. In ubuntu is easy:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

4.- Allow .htaccess in server's config

```
<Directory /your_wp_dir>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

5.- After any change in server's config restart it (again in ubuntu is):

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of Apache are you using? Also, make sure you check a test page with

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

and CTRL+F for "mod_rewrite".

Comment: My php version is 5.2.17
and i didn't find "mod_rewrite"
Is there any solution??

Comment: @user1932682 see my answer! I put it info about enable `mod_rewrite`

Comment: Sorry for the log delay, still getting used to participating. Anyway, you _need_ mod_requite in order to "rewrite" the PHP files to permalinks. Check out the answer below this one, I think @NomikOS has this stuff down to a science.